# WPF bind ComboBox ItemSouce to an ObservableCollection and the SelectedItem to a DataContext model property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF, and I am interested can this be done or not.
I hava a string datasource for my combobox controll defined in the MainWindow lie this:

```
public readonly ObservableCollection<string> _roles = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "User", "Admin", "Developer" };
```

I have a model defined:

```
public class LoginRequest : ValidationBase
    {
        private string _email;
        private string _password;
        private string _role;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set { SetValue(ref _email, value); }
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password minimum length is 8 charachters.")]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set { SetValue(ref _password, value); }
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role is required")]
        public string Role
        {
            get { return _role; }
            set { SetValue(ref _role, value); }
        }
    }
```

This model is defines in xaml as my DataContext

<Window.DataContext>
<model:LoginRequest />
</Window.DataContext>

In the form I have a ComboBox where I bind the Role property of my object. That works perfect if I set the combobox ItemSource property form the code like this:

```
cbRoles.ItemsSource = _roles;
```

But I am interested, can I do this i xaml?
Here is my code snippet for my combobox.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label x:Name="lblRole" 
                   Content="Role" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Role,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                    NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SimpleStringProperty}"
                 SelectedValuePath="{Binding SimpleStringProperty}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SimpleStringProperty}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                 Text="Select Option"
                 Margin="1"
                 Height="20"
                 x:Name="cbRoles"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Role ...}"` seems nonsense when Role is a single string. Did you mean to bind `SelectedItem` to Role? Note also that setting `SelectedValuePath` has no effect without a `SelectedValue` binding or assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` from XAML you must use data binding. To use data binding, the source *must* be a `public` property, which requires to convert the `_roles` field to a `public` property.

Since the items are plain string, it doesn't have any property and therefore no path. You can't select a property to provide the display value or selection value. `ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath` and `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath` must be removed.

`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` by default.

`SimpleStringProperty` does not exist on `LoginRequest`. `SelectedItem` should bind to `LoginRequest.Role` instead.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> Roles { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Roles = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "User", "Admin", "Developer" };
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Roles, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}},
                                NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Role}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```